# How this statement should be written?

Tags: logic, logic-translation

If I have a theorem/conjecture of the form "Let $n$ be an [object with some properties], then $P(n)$", how would it be written in logic ? So I have 2 variants:
1)$\forall n \in A, P(n)$.
2)$(n\in A)\to(P(n))$.
(By $A$ I mean a set of all such objects with some property).
So is one of my variants right ? Or it should be written in some other form ?

Comment: So it would be kind of equivalent ?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA No I meant,are variants I have written equivalent ?Because in my second variant I have no quantifiers, or we can transform second variant using universal generalization ?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Yeah, now I realized that the second statement can be true some $n$ and false for the others, so I need "for all" claim anyway, thanks for explaining.

Comment: In so-called '[Agda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agda_(programming_language)) notation' for dependent type theory, the notation $(n \in A) \to P(n)$ refers to the dependent product type $\prod_{n \in A} P(n)$, which corresponds with the proposition $\forall n \in A,\,P(n)$ under the Curry-Howard correspondence. I'm leaving this as a comment rather than an answer because it would not be considered correct notation in mainstream mathematics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$(n\in A)\to P(n)$ is a good start, but you need something to express the idea that you want this to be true for *all* $n$. So you should write
$$ \forall n : \bigl[ n\in A \to P(n) \bigr] $$

This is what "$\forall n\in A. P(n)$" (with variations in punctuation that don't carry any meaning) is usually considered to be an *abbreviation* for in formal logic.